# to calculate the expected value of a somehow modified logit-normal distribution

Tags: probability, integration

$Z = 1/(1+(e^{-x}+e^{-y})/e^{-w})$, where $w$ $x$ and $y$ are independent standard normal variables.
I guess the expected value of $Z$ is $1/3$, but don't know how to prove it.
The result by MC sampling is 0.3333403686846405.

for
$Z = 1/(1+e^{-y}+e^{-x})$, the simuation is 0.3092217.

Comment: Are the variables x and y independent?

Comment: I've calculated $0.309229$. It is close to your simulation, but still different.

Comment: Hi, you are right,my simulation is 0.3092217,cause I made a mistake in the former expression. but still thanks a lot for your answer!